# Parser error after add service reference

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, wcf

I've add Service Reference after build and run i got a parser error with detail

```
 Reference.svcmap: Method 'get_LocalPath' in type 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.ServerRequest' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin, Version=1.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.
```

it happened when I change ASP.NET web app target framework from `4.0` to `4.7.1` but my WCF Services was .NET Framework `4.0`

```
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3056.0
```

Comment: This means between the versions there where obviously implementation-changes. An change 4.0 to 4.7 is quite a major step.

Comment: So, I must find out how different they were ?

Comment: I think, if you want a 4.0 App be 4.7 ready, it’s easier to create a new 4.7 Project and try to add the functionality of your old app, than trying to port your old app to 4.7...There where many changes.